# Relationship between users and items tables in a database

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I have two tables in a database: A users_table and a items_table. I need a way to be able to define which items each user gets access to. I thought to create a third table containing: 'user_id', 'item_id', and 'has_access' columns.

The problem I am having is that the users_table as well as the items_table have 'active' columns that can change. Users can only get access to items that are active. Items can only be assigned to users that are active. Thus when a user/item is set to inactive all of the records in the third table that refer to that user/item should be set to inactive. Same goes for when a user/item gets deleted in their respective tables.

When a new user gets added they should automatically get assigned all of the items (has_access = false). When a new item gets added to the items_table, all users should automatically get assigned the new item (again, with column has_access set to false).

The reason for this is I want to simply be able to make a SQl query such as SELECT * FROM users-items_table WHERE user_id='someId', and use the information returned to build up a profile for the user containing the items they have access to.

How would I set up the relationship between the tables to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserItems table doesn't need an HasAccess field. If a record exists in this table for a combination of UserId and ItemId, it means the user has access to the item. If you want to revoke access, delete the record.

So I would definately advise against this:

> When a new user gets added they should automatically get assigned all
>   of the items (has_access = false). When a new item gets added to the
>   items_table, all users should automatically get assigned the new item
>   (again, with column has_access set to false).

Assigning an item to a user is as simple as adding a record in the UserItems table.

```
INSERT INTO UserItems (userId, itemId) VALUES (123, 456);
```

To query, you simply join the tables together. Don't forget to check for active items. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Item
   INNER JOIN UserItems ON Item.Id = UserItems.ItemId
   WHERE UserItems.UserId = 123
      AND Item.IsActive = true;
```

This will return all active items that are assigned to a user.

If you want to see, for example, all users that have a certain item assigned, turn the query around:

```
SELECT * FROM User
   INNER JOIN UserItems ON User.Id = UserItems.UserId
   WHERE UserItems.ItemId = 456
      AND User.IsActive = true;
```

As a sidenote, don't name your tables *users_table* or *items_table*. The convention is to use *User* and *Item*. For join tables, the convention is to make the second part plural: *UserItems*.

Comment: Thank you for your informative answer, this helped me a lot!